# Como solucionar error consola: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400

Tags: mercadopago, woocommerce

En un sitio `wordpress` utilizando `woocommerce` y el plugin oficial de Mercado Pago, las opciones de envió no se despliegan (entonces no se puede proseguir con el pago) y en la consola obtengo el siguiente error

> api.mercadopago.com/modules/tracking/checkout?token=&referer=https%3A//jimenacocinatienda.com
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400
>   (Bad Request)

Alquien sabe que podría estar causando esto? Y alguna posible solución?

Comment: tengo el mismo problema pero no estoy usando mercadopago, sino amazon y paypal. Cuando indican el cambio de https por http ¿en dónde lo cambian?¿eso no inhabilita el certificado ssl?
En mi caso arroja el mismo informe pero en la consola en google chrome me indica que tiene que ver con el link de fonts.googleapis.
Desactivé y active plugins, realmente no se qué hacer.
Les agradecería respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Pasé por algo parecido hace un día, y era porque tenía `https` en mi URL; se lo cambié a `http`, y con eso funcionó, pero también le tuve que poner un `/` al final de la URL.

Espero te pueda servir. Saludos.